# UPDATE QUERY Image

Tags: arrays, vb.net, image, visual-studio-2010

if I try to convert an image into an array and then run the update query and insert the string update the transformed image matrix I get the error:

> the + operator is not defined for types 'String' and 'matrix' 1-byte
>   size

the code is:

```
data1 = textbox 
data2 = TextBox2 
using ms as new MemoryStream () 
DirectCast (picturebox1.image, botmap) .save (ms currentFormat) 
image = ms.toArray () 
end using 
Dim param as SqlParameter () = _ new SqlParameter () {new SqlParameter ("@ data1", _ data1), new SqlParameter ("@ data2", data2), new SqlParameter ("@ image", image)}
 mcmd.commandText = "update set table column1 = '" + data1 + "', column2 '" + data1 + "'" 
 mcmd.parameters.add ("@ image", SqlDbType.varbinary, 8000) .Value = image
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: How can we help you without seeing what you have done in code?

Comment: What language is this? post the code you already have to help people answer your question.

Comment: the code is: data1 = textbox 
data2 = TextBox2 
using ms as new MemoryStream () 
DirectCast (picturebox1.image, botmap) .save (ms currentFormat) 
image = ms.toArray () 
end using 

Dim param as SqlParameter () = _ 
new SqlParameter () {new SqlParameter ("@ data1", _ 
data1), new SqlParameter ("@ data2", data2), new SqlParameter ("@ image", image)} 
mcmd.commandText = "update set table column1 = '" + data1 + "', column2 '" + data1 + "'" 
mcmd.parameters.add ("@ image", SqlDbType.varbinary, 8000) .Value = image

Comment: I'm using vb in visual studio 2010

Comment: Take a look at this post. You will get the idea http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database

Comment: convert image to line array works but the string sql that returns: 

the + operator is not defined for types 'String' and 'matrix' 1-byte size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are anyways, defining a parameter for `image` variable in your code as pointed below

```
mcmd.parameters.add ("@image", SqlDbType.varbinary, 8000) .Value = image
```

So, instead of preparing your query by concatenating the values which is also vulnerable to SQL Injection attack; use parametrized query with the parameters you have already defined

```
mcmd.commandText = "update table_name set column1 = @data1, column2 = @data2, image = @image
```

Comment: I tried to change the string as shown but the compiler returns exception type @ date1 undefined

Comment: Have you at all created/added the parameter @date1? I have given a link in comment; go through it and try doing accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant data1

Comment: I should find an alternative to concatenate string and arrays, any ideas?

Comment: NO, you shouldn't concatenate. rather pass the parameter having image byte[] as shown in answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, even following the link posted does not work, I always have the problem that once converted into an image array and then when I go to use the string sql update I get the exception chaining